# Parsing text file character causes Integer.parseInt to fail, shows up in println but not JOptionPane text?

Tags: java, parsing, unicode

I am trying to parse some text from a text file and then parse the text to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt`. This keep failing as the result of a character in the file that I cannot "see".

When using `System.out.println` the charter is shown almost as a single quote but much smaller, almost point like. When it is printed in a `JOptionPane` it does not show up.

[image]

In the text file itself the character does not show up either when viewing it in Notepad or Notepad++. Also the start of this text is also the beginning of a new line.

Is there a way to trim this character from the text? Is my only solution to use RegEx to parse out only number characters?

**EDIT:** The string 491034 is also the start of the file, not the start of a newline.

Comment: What happens when you do a `substring(1,text.length)`

Comment: I know it's generally advised against, but is it possible to use the instanceof operator to verify you have a recognized character beforehand?

Comment: What is the input data?

Comment: And no, regex isn't your only solution. You could use isDigit()

Comment: You can use `java.text.normalizer` to remove Unicode characters that are not in the "normal" ASCII character set.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider it is a csv (deliminated by `|`) that was exported from excel.

Comment: @Petro I guess that would solve the problem but if these/this character shows up elsewhere I still have an issue.

Comment: @Petro sending the text through the `Normalizer` with the `Normalizer.Form.NFC` produces the same results, though I don't know what the form represents. I will try the others.

Comment: @Tom That is the solution. Before I delete this, what is "BOM"?

Comment: Google for "byte order mark" for more information about it.

Comment: @Tom that's the easy solution, I just wanted your personal opinion on it. JK, not sure why I asked.